# What is a "random" method of picking the start player at which a person could cheat?

Tags: game-design, playing-cards, dice, random

I'm writing a kid's book in which the characters use cards or dice to decide who goes first--and eventually start using the method to determine who has to do certain chores such as washing the dishes. It's supposedly random, but it turns out the father is cheating somehow (perhaps through math). The daughter (12 years old) wonders why she is always losing, and figures out how he is tricking her. (This ties in with themes of the book--the child is being lied to in other ways as well!)

Can anyone help me out? I am not much of a game player myself. The book is a mystery, though, so I want a small example of how she is getting smarter at "deduction."

What method could they use, and how could she use logic to figure it out?

If you can help, thank you so much! :o)

Comment: There are plenty of "random" methods for choosing things that are not really random depending on the setting.

Comment: I don't see how this is opinion based - perhaps there could be differences of opinion on what would seem random, but the closing reason doesn't seem right to me.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure this is opinion based. Seems like it would be relatively simple to say "this is a list of commonly used random deciders that you could cheat at." I'm genuinely confused why it would be closed as opinion based.

Comment: "*she is always losing*": does it have to be "always"?  Would "usually" be okay too?

Comment: I think this has been closed because of the additional question in the text: "*how could she use logic to figure it out?*", which asks people to speculate. You might delete that entire line and concentrate on the original Title question, then ask for it to be reopened.  In general on SE sites, it's a good idea to ask one simple and well-defined question at a time.